# How to store data with multer outside of the project folder?

Tags: node.js, api, file, storage, multer

I want to save a form file outside of the project folder. For that I started using

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null,  __dirname + 'uploads')
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now())
  }
})
```

but __dirname is already inside my project folder. Are there any methods reach out to a path out of the folder? Thank you!

Comment: As mentioned many times before in SO, you just need to use Path (it's included in Node.js, no need to install anything new). Specifically, the method Path.resolve() will let you "paste" as many strings as you need in order to create a valid path to store in your filesystem.

Comment: Thank you, this helps. Unfortunately I didn't see your previous answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use the `..` notation to go up one folder, or specify a root relative path that starts with `/`.

Say you want to save your files in the folder located at `/home/john/uploads` and your project is in `/home/john/myproject`. Both of the following would work:

```js
destination: function (req, file, cb) {
  cb(null,  '/home/john/uploads');
  // or
  cb(null,  '../uploads');
},
```